# How to use file name to sort and count files stored in a .mat file?

Tags: matlab, count, filenames

`dbhole.mat` file contains files name like: `d1h1`,`d1h2`,`d1h3`,`d1h4`,`d2h1`,`d2h2`,`d3h1`,`d3h2`,`d3h4`,`d3h5`,`d3h6`.

I want to count the number of files having a name that starts with `d1` then `d2` ,`d3` and so on in a loop.

Comment: It contains filenames or variable names?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: it contains file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to get a list of the *variables* in a *.mat file that start with `d1`, `d2`, etc. You could use `who` and `matfile` to get a list of all variables. `who` accepts a regular expression which you can create specific to the variables you want to see.

```
matobj = matfile('filename.mat');

d1vars = who(matobj, '-regexp', '^d1h');
nD1 = numel(d1vars);
```

Or more generally in a loop

```
for k = 1:3
    vars{k} = who(matobj, '-regexp', ['^d', num2str(k), 'h']);

    % And get the number
    nVars(k) = numel(vars{k});
end
```

If you have an older version of MATLAB, you can load the file into a `struct` and then check the fields of that struct for the pattern that you'd like.

```
data = load('filename.mat');
variables = fieldnames(data);

isd1 = variables(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(variables, '^d1h')));
nD1 = numel(isd1);
```

Comment: if the file starts with name d10, d11 etc. then using above code it will count this d10 also which i don't want. actually there are files named d1h1...d1h22 , then d2h1...d2h18, then d3h1...d3h23 so on till d14h1..d14h20. So i want result  individually that files name starts with d1 are 22 in numbers, files start with d2 are 18 in numbers and so on. Just want to index out using for loop

Comment: @aryan Updated so it should be able to handle those